# I can't get this map with buttons to span but it works ok for another map where is the problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spanned, makestyles

I learn JavaScript React and now I have this question:

I have this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-new-content-map-list-not-spanning-bipxs?file=/src/FileList.jsx)

In the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) about `span` I read but I can't get the buttons in the image here to span like they do on the right side:

I removed the `span` code and now tried with css but no luck. I think I have tried all the tricks in the book so I must be missing something really beginner mistake.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrapped your tag with a `div` which is a block element. Remove this `<div className="tagInput">` . It should work fine .